# How to check if a variable contains mysqli result?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to mod a script written for MySQL to mysqli and have been successful up to this error:

> Warning: get_resource_type() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given (etc)

Here is the code:

```
  function free_result($queryid=-1)
  {
    if($queryid != -1)
    {
      $this->queryid = $queryid;
    }
    if((get_resource_type($this->queryid)==='mysql result') && is_resource($this->queryid))
      return @mysql_free_result($this->queryid);
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to change this to update it to mysqli.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the old [MySQL](http://php.net/mysql) functions, [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) methods don't return resources. They either return an object or some other string/integer/boolean/null type. The error message is crystal clear. The function `get_resource_type()` expects a resource, as an argument, and you're giving it an object.

Be sure to read about [Types](http://php.net/language.types) in PHP for clarification on the differences between [resource types](http://php.net/language.types.resource) and [object types](http://php.net/language.types.object).

My guess here is that you expect `$this->queryid` to be a [`MySQLi_Result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, and that's what you're trying to check for. So rather than `get_resource_type()` use the [`instanceof`](http://php.net/instanceof) operator instead, to check the object's type.

```
  function free_result($queryid = -1) {
    if($queryid != -1) {
      $this->queryid = $queryid;
    }
    
    if($this->queryid instanceof MySQLi_Result)
      return mysqli_free_result($this->queryid);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you can just Type Hint the function's prototype to only accept objects of type `MySQLi_Result` to simplify your code and make it easier to test.

```
  function free_result(MySQLi_Result $queryid = null) {
    if($queryid) {
      $this->queryid = $queryid;
    }
    
    if($this->queryid instanceof MySQLi_Result) {
        return mysqli_free_result($this->queryid);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Also, please stop using the error silence operator `@`. No good can ever come of that.

Make sure you're calling `mysqli_free_result()` and not the old `mysql_free_result()` function, also, as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that MySQli returns an object instead of a resource. So you should test for that

```
If($query instanceof mysqli_result)
```